# SQL - How to Select Entries in a Column that Share Entries in another Column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a Relational Oracle Database via Toad for Oracle.

I have a table in the Database like this:

| LOT_CODE | LOT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1000817454 | 1352341501 |
| 1000817455 | 1312341501 |
| 1000817503 | 1322341601 |
| 1000817504 | 1372341601 |
| 1000817535 | 1352341501 |

I would like to select LOT_CODES that Share a LOT_ID.

So, in the table above, the answer would be LOT_CODES  1000817454 and 1000817535, since they both Share LOT_ID  1352341501.

But I'd like the Answer to be such that it Counts the instances of LOT_IDs based on how many LOT_CODES have that LOT_ID.

So the Desired Output (based on my sample table above would be):

| LOT_ID | TOTAL_REPETITIONS |
| --- | --- |
| 1352341501 | 2 |
| 1312341501 | 1 |
| 1322341601 | 1 |
| 1372341601 | 1 |

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears you are just asking for a vanilla aggregation

```
select LOT_ID, Count(LOT_CODE) TOTAL_REPETITIONS
from t
group by LOT_ID;
```

Comment: D'oh!
Thank you Stu! Much Appreciated!
It was probably a stupid question on my part!

I'm still a novice with SQL.
Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

A simple GROUP BY will do the trick.

Your last result would be more interesting:

```
SELECT
"LOT_ID" , COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY "LOT_ID"
```

| LOT_ID | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1352341501 | 2 |
| 1312341501 | 1 |
| 1322341601 | 1 |
| 1372341601 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EzE8lg3g)